# Google Script code running forever - How to terminate - calling Urlfetch constantly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, infinite-loop, terminate

I have a Google App script (GAS) add-on for Sheets in 'Google Workspace Marketplace'.
The Script calling Urlfetch to get data from our API.

One user created a sheet that now calling the API forever.
The user does not have the sheet open in any webbrowser.

I can see in Logs that the API calls never stops. Over 20k every day.
I talked to user and checked his sheet. There is no triggers or loops. On my account the users sheet works fine.

What can I do to stop this script from running forever, for this user?
Is any way in Google Admin to stop the script from running?

Any help is appreciated,

Br,
Henrik

Comment: Must be Clientside?
The user Sheet calls Urlfetch to get data from API.   
But I know Urlfetch is running on Google server so I guess the server get stuck in some eternal loop?

Comment: The code is quite big. 
Yes - Custom functions calling API.
Custom menu for user to add API Key.

Comment: I think the Google Server handle the Urlftech has hanged. It never stops. today I tried to create a new version of Addon to see if the API calls stopped. It did not. It continues. Very strange.

Comment: What's triggering this function? When you say `I can see in Logs that the API calls never stops`, you mean the logs in Apps Script or in your API? In Apps Script, you see the function getting executed many times?

Comment: The user can trigger the URL fetch from custom function OR from a Menu 'Refresh' button. In this case its not known how the functions was triggered. The users Sheet has around 1000 API calls (big sheet) and I can see in Google Apps Script Log that the calls in looping. There is 1000 calls in log and then stops and wait for some random time of maybe 20min and starts over again. Today I had 30k api calls in last 24h from this sheet. I dont know how to stop it.

Comment: Since this is only reproducible with specific accounts, I'd suggest you to contact [Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?authuser=0), if you have access to it.

Comment: @AlanWells Please post your solution here and I can give credit to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Apps Script file can "see" the code executions of your add-on users.  You can also terminate executions.

Open up the list of your projects:
https://script.google.com/home/my

Find the project that your add-on is based on.
Click the 3 dots at the right.
Choose "Executions"
Click the "Add filter" button with the plus sign.
Choose "Ran As".
Choose "Anyone"
Click Apply.
You will see executions that are being run from your add-on users.
Click in the filter address bar again to add another filter.
Choose "Status".
Click the "Running" checkbox.
If you see a very long running execution, then click the 3 dots icon.
Choose
**TERMINATE**